# Innosetup/MSIWrapper 1603 Installation error: Error ModifyRegistry - getting UninstallString

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I didn't find any similar problems Googleing or on Stackoverflow. I'm having a hard time getting the installer to work, the installer is created with [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and then wrapped to *.msi* using [MSIWrapper](http://www.exemsi.com/). I created the installer and the program installs but it always returns the 1603 error code (I need it to be successful for automated installations). It seems the installer can't find my application, or at least the uninstall key, in the registry, I tried changing the keys, creating fresh installation, setting the flag to create the Uninstall key explicitly etc., I'm running out of ideas...

Here's a small part of the installation log:

```
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- Modify registry
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ModifyRegistry: Start.
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ModifyRegistry for application id {660F88C6-D271-4A56-81C5-8965E5E5144D}
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ReadRegStr: Key=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{660F88C6-D271-4A56-81C5-8965E5E5144D}, ValueName=UninstallString, 32 bit
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ReadRegStr: Unable to open key.
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ReadRegStr: Key=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{660F88C6-D271-4A56-81C5-8965E5E5144D}, ValueName=UninstallString, 64 bit
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ReadRegStr: Unable to open key.
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ReadRegStr: Key=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{660F88C6-D271-4A56-81C5-8965E5E5144D}, ValueName=UninstallString, default
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ReadRegStr: Unable to open key.
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- ModifyRegistry: Error getting UninstallString value from registry.
-- CUSTOM ACTION -- Error modifying registry.
CustomAction bz.EarlyInstallFinish2 returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 8:48:10: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

**Note:** This happens even if I uninstall the app and try a fresh install...

The whole log: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1zpczamuj3bgy7/install_error.log?dl=0)

Comment: Windows will put UninstallString in the registry *for informational puposes only* because it will not use it to uninstall the product. I don't know what you want that string for, but you don't need it to do an uninstall - just use an msiexec /x command or call the relevant API such as MsiConfigureProduct() or equivalent.

Comment: When the installer runs it returns an error (error code 1603) cause it can't find the key...

Comment: Strictly speaking the installer throws a 1603 because the custom action failed.  Based on the custom action logging it's only assumed that it's because it can't find the key. Without looking at the custom action source it's very difficult to know for sure the reason.

Comment: We all understand that the issue is that the key does not exist yet, causing the code to crash and a 1603 return. The point I am making is that if you are hoping to get this value, alter it, and write it back to the registry (as one example of things people try) then it's pointless because Windows does not use the UninstallString to uninstall a Windows Installer package. Even when you get this working there may be no point to what you are doing. Note also that if you know the ProductCode of your package you do not need to know the UninstallString anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do something with the uninstall key for the product you are installing.  If so, the problem is you have the custom action bz.EarlyInstallFinish2  scheduled before the standard action  [PublishProduct Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370932(v=vs.85).aspx) so therefore the key doesn't exist yet (race condition).

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to resolve the issue, maybe disable the custom action? I use a default/bare bones script created with Innosetup's wizard and don't really know how to approach the problem. This is the [script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vj58f84d4i14chd/install_script.iss?dl=0). Or maybe this problem is related to the MSIWrapper around the original .exe installation?